# sorting file names with version

Tags: sort, version

I am trying to sort file names in a directory as below.

```
$ ls -1v
file-1.10.0-114.1.1.x86.tb1_2.rpm  
file-1.10.0-114.2.2.x86.tb1_2.rpm  
file-1.10.0-114.11.2.x86.tb1_2.rpm  
file-1.10.0-114.x86.tb1_2.rpm  
file-1.10.0-115.1.1.x86.tb1_2.rpm  
file-1.10.0-115.2.2.x86.tb1_2.rpm  
file-1.10.0-115.3.1.x86.tb1_2.rpm  
file-1.10.0-115.22.1.x86.tb1_2.rpm  
file-1.10.0-115.x86.tb1_2.rpm
```

But, my expectation was the below.

```
file-1.10.0-114.x86.tb1_2.rpm  
file-1.10.0-114.1.1.x86.tb1_2.rpm  
file-1.10.0-114.2.2.x86.tb1_2.rpm  
file-1.10.0-114.11.2.x86.tb1_2.rpm  
file-1.10.0-115.x86.tb1_2.rpm  
file-1.10.0-115.1.1.x86.tb1_2.rpm  
file-1.10.0-115.2.2.x86.tb1_2.rpm  
file-1.10.0-115.3.1.x86.tb1_2.rpm  
file-1.10.0-115.22.1.x86.tb1_2.rpm
```

I tried `sort -V`, but it showed the same result.
How do I sort like this way?

Comment: version don't exist on POSIX. It is just a file naming convention on POSIX. The names are sorted alphanumerically

Comment: I'm confused, are you expecting `file-1.10.0-115.x86.tb1_2.rpm` to be sorted as if it was `file-1.10.0-115.0.0.x86.tb1_2.rpm`?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: yes and no, the `-v` switch already makes `ls` put `.22.` after `.2.` and `.3.`.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041210/how-can-i-sort-file-names-by-version-numbers

Answer (score 12):

Try to use this command:

```
ls -h | sort -t. -k3,3 -k4,4n
```

`ls -h` - standard output of ls command (you can use ls -lh with the same result provided the user and group names don't contain dots);

`-t.` - setting up the separator for sort command;

`-k3,3` - sorting by third field

and after this ...

`-k4,4n` - sorting by fourth field numerically

Comment: but that would sort a `file-1.10.0-93.11.2.x86.tb1_2.rpm` after `file-1.10.0-115.22.1.x86.tb1_2.rpm` as the sort on the 3rd field is not numerical.

Comment: That would also sort `file-1.10.0-115.1.10.x86.tb1_2.rpm` before `file-1.10.0-115.1.2.x86.tb1_2.rpm`

Comment: Thanks for the comments. You are absolutely right. These exceptions will not be handled correctly. But if the values are between 0-100 and 0-999 just like in the author's example, everything will be fine.

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`, you can do:

```
print -rl file*.rpm(noe:'REPLY=${REPLY%.x*}':)
```

That is do a numeric (`n`) sort on the file name stripped of the trailing `.x*` part.

You can do something similar with GNU `sort` with:

```
ls | sort -Vtx -k 1,1
```

assuming there's no `x` anywhere else, though that one would have issues with file names containing newline characters.

Or you could do:

```
print -rl file*.rpm(noe:'REPLY=${REPLY//(#m)<->/Z$MATCH}':)
```

(with `extendedglob`) where we prefix every number with `Z` so the `Z115.xZ86...` sorts before the `Z115.Z1...`.